# Full width image, stop layout changing while loading

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a full width image that is displayed at the top of a page. Before the image loads the space for it has height 0, but after it loads it pushes down the whole content, thus making an unpleasing **loading flicker**.

This is usually solved by setting the **height** of the image via **CSS** so that the space for the image is computed and *reserved* before the image loads so that after it does the layout is not altered. In my case it doesn't work (not directly at least) as I don't know the **height** of the image: being a full width image its height is actually determined by the width of the viewport.

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Is there any pure CSS way to fix this issue (reserve the space for the image before it loads, only by knowing the image size)?

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/px6eg7c5/1/)

**LE:** I just noticed that this could be solved if there was some sort of placeholder element that has the same attributes as the image (eg: add an element at the top which has the same width/height as the source image and also has a 100% width style attribute), this way the space required by the image would actually be used by that placeholder element.

Comment: seems to work in that demo...

Comment: @Johannes I don't want the content to be pushed down after the image loads. I want the green div to be at the same position before and after the image loads. Before the image loads there should only be white space at the top, before the content, where the image will be. PS: I'm using Google Chrome

Comment: okay, I just saw: It works if the container is wider than high (which I had at first). Your description is true when the container is higher than wide. I know, that doesn't help, but still, it might be a cue to the solution...

Comment: Hello, there is js  way to solve it, but I dont think there is css way to fix it

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in comment I dont know and I think there is no css solution for this problem but I created jQuery solution, it might help, hopefully will do :)

Image wrap into container and set height before image is loaded

```
$(function() {
  var originalW = 1920;
  var originalH = 800;
  var ratio = originalH / originalW;
  $(".image-wrap").css({
    height: $("body").width() * ratio
  })
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/px6eg7c5/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle that does what you want (at least it looks like): https://jsfiddle.net/Lhd801eu/  (edited, too small image at first)

The problem in your fiddle seemed to have been the fiddle site itself: The `<img>`tag also had `id="img"` and no real `src`attribute, which seems to be not-so-goood...

I changed the ID to "xxx" (meaningless, can be anything) and into the src-attribute I put the URL of some file in that I found on a photo site (That image size is about 1MB, which doesn't load immediately)

Seems to work this way... (?)

Comment: What you did is actually set the image src to the same file, which gets cached by the browser and you don't have to load it anymore. This only stops **you** from seeing the bug. If you clear your cache you will still see it. So, this has nothing to do with the actual question. Changing the ID of the image only stopped the JS I wrote to work (JS which loads a different image every time so browser doesn't cache it).

Comment: I emptied the cache every time before I tried it - I am aware of that. And I also changed the URL several times to other images of similar size. And I still didn't see it happen, at least not on the JS fiddle page

Comment: BTW the browser caches not only the last file/image, but many more, so also with your JS all these images will be in the browser cache once they were called (unless you clear the cache every time or deactivate it, as I did when I tested this)...

Comment: Yes it does, but that's why I use JS, so every time it loads a different image which is not in the cache (so that you can see the loading bug). Actually, with my specific JS script it will load up to 100 different images, as I always append a random number to the image source, the number being between 0 and 99.